# Window service to send mail

Tags: windows-services

I need to create a Windows service with VS 2010 that can send mail to another system on the same Local Area Network.

Please reply to me with the code I need to use for this scenario.

Lots of thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This is place for more detail questions, with what you have problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a .Net service, using System.Net.Mail to send the mail and the local SMTP server as the server. You will then need an email server on the receiver as well, either Exchange or a free option such as Mercury.